# What is the naming convention for craters on Mercury?

Tags: mercury, naming, crater

The two largest craters on Mercury are names Caloris (meaning "hot") and Rembrandt (for the painter). So there doesn't seem to be a pattern.

By convention, craters on Mars are named for people who studied the planet (like Cassini) or wrote about it (like Bradbury).

Is there a similar naming convention for the craters at the surface of Mercury?

Comment: Just a note that your second paragraph is incorrect via incomplete information: Only craters >50 km fit into the naming scheme you wrote.  Smaller craters on Mars are named after small towns and villages. https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/Page/Categories .  That page also gives the themes for all features on all bodies for which a system has been established, including Mercury craters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [quick search](https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=mercury%20crater%20names) returns that wikipedia has an extensive list how different things are named on various celestial bodies.

For [Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_nomenclature#Mercury)'s craters it quotes "[Famous deceased artists, musicians, painters, authors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_craters_on_Mercury)". As source of its wisdom it gives the IAU working group on [planetary system nomenclature](https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/SearchResults?target=MERCURY&featureType=Crater,%20craters) as authoritive source for them - the source which decides on official naming.